# Prove f(x) = sin(1/x) , x is irrational and 0 , x is rational is not Riemann integrable.

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

*Question*

Prove $f:[0,1] \rightarrow R$ defined by

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
& sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &&, x \in (R-Q) \cap [0,1] \\
&0 &&, otherwise
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
is not Riemann integrable.

*The author goes like this:*

> Consider a partition $$P=\left\{0,\frac 2 {(2n+1)\pi},\frac 2
>  {(2n-1)\pi},\cdots,\frac 2 {3\pi},\frac 2 {\pi},1\right\}.$$ Then the
> upper sum $U(f,P)=1$ as $\sup f(x)$ in every sub interval is $1$. The
> lower sum $L(f,P)=-\frac 2 {\pi}$;for, the contribution of the last
> interval $[\frac 2 {\pi},1]$ is $0$ since the minimum of the function
> is $0$.But in each of the other sub-intervals, the minimum is $-1$ and
> so the lower sum is $(-1)\times$ legth of all the sub intervals in
> $[0,\frac 2 {\pi}]$ which is $(-1)\times \frac 2 {\pi}=-\frac 2
> > {\pi}$. This proves that $f\not\in R[0,1].$

*My problem*

In the book the author first takes a partition , then finds upper darboux sum and lower darboux sum then concludes that f is not riemann integrable.

Is this proof okay?

I mean there might be a partition for which $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \lt \epsilon$ is true.

**EDITED on 9th December 2020**

Deleted photos and added text.

Comment: Your doubt is genuine. +1 for questioning textbook proofs. Your book proof is supposedly based on the following theorem: if $P_n$ is a sequence of partitions such that norm/mesh of $P_n$ tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty $, then $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n) $ tends to $0$. Here you are given a sequence of partitions based on different values of $n$. The problem with the proof is that the norm / mesh of partitions is not tending to $0$.

Comment: You need to find out the points at which the function is discontinuous. You will find that the function is continuous only at points where $x=1/n\pi$ where $n$ is a positive integer.